# Error when passing edited conf file to mosquitto in docker container

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I get this error when trying to run mosquitto docker on ubuntu.

docker: Error response from daemon: source /var/lib/docker/overlay2/a9ce020a555f57/merged/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf is not directory.

I'm running this command.

sudo docker run -it -p 1883:1883 -p 9001:9001 -v mosquitto.conf:/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf eclipse-mosquitto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)

> When you use a bind mount, a file or directory on the host machine is mounted into a container. The file or directory is referenced by its **absolute path** on the host machine.

So you have to pass the full (absolute) path to the `mosquitto.conf` e.g. `/home/jay/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf` (see [this issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/4830) for info on why). You can get your [shell to help](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#start-a-container-with-a-bind-mount):

```
sudo docker run -it -p 1883:1883 -p 9001:9001 -v "$(pwd)"/mosquitto.conf:/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf eclipse-mosquitto
```